# Changing value of a ThemeResource at runtime does not reflect in other views

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am using custom themedictionary in my UWP app. I change the value of a ThemeResource at runtime. This change is reflected only in the mainview and not the other views. Even if i create a new view after changing the resource's value the new view uses only the intial value of the resource. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

This is how I change my resource's value.

```
(Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
```

My Secondary View's XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
```

Even my main view has the same XAML.

Here's the complete project. [Download Repo as zip](https://github.com/Kumara-Krishnan/ThemePOC/archive/master.zip)

Comment: I am using style instead of theme! By using style we can update look & feel with out restarting app.

Comment: https://github.com/Kumara-Krishnan/ThemePOC

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Even after changing the resource's value, the secondary view still has the value specified initially in the resource dictionary.

Comment: Can't use binding if i am using multiple views which causes marshal exception

Comment: @Romasz Secondly if it can update the UI elements which use the resource in one view? why cant it update in other open views? Have you seen my sample?

Comment: I haven't taken a look at your sample, will do it after I return home.

Comment: @Romasz Also the default mail app is able to acheive this. check the personalisation -> Colours option in default mail app with multiple windows opened.

Comment: I've tested your sample and now see the problem. I would follow @JayZuo-MSFT answer.

Comment: You are right. Though, I don't know how to force the view to not to recreate initial dictionary (what seems to happen) or refresh the UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd think this is by design. When we create multiple windows for an app, each window behaves independently. Each window operates in its own thread. The `Application.Resources` used in each window is also independent.

[Application.Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_Resources) is a [ResourceDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary) object and [ResourceDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary) class inherits from [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject), so `Application.Resources` is also a `DependencyObject` instance.

> **All [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject) instances must be created on the UI thread that is associated with the current [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window) for an app.** This is enforced by the system, and there are two important implications of this for your code:
>
> - Code that uses API from two [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject) instances will always be run on the same thread, which is always the UI thread. You don't typically run into threading issues in this scenario.
> - Code that is not running on the main UI thread cannot access a [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject) directly because a [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject) has thread affinity to the UI thread only. Only code that runs on the UI thread can change or even read the value of a dependency property. For example a worker thread that you've initiated with a .NET **Task** or an explicit [ThreadPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.threading.threadpool) thread won't be able to read dependency properties or call other APIs.

For more info, please see **DependencyObject and threading** under [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject#remarks) of [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject).

So each [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window) has its own `Application.Resources`. In secondary view, the `Application.Resources` is re-evaluated from your `ResourceDictionary`. The `BackgroundBrush` would not be affected by the setting in main view as with the following code

```
(Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
```

you are only changing the `Application.Current.Resources` instance associated with main view's [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window).

If you want the secondary view to use the same brush as the main view, I think you can store this color in main view and then apply it when creating secondary view. For example, I add a static field named `BackgroundBrushColor` in `App` class and then use it like the following:

```
private void ThemeChanger_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.BackgroundBrushColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)), Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)), Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)), Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)));

    (Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = App.BackgroundBrushColor;
}

private async Task CreateNewViewAsync()
{
    CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;

    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        (Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = App.BackgroundBrushColor;

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondaryPage), null);
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
        Window.Current.Activate();

        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
}
```

---

> I have changed the code to modify the resource in each view. if you set a breakpoint in ThemeChanged method in SecondaryPage.xaml.cs before changing the value you can see that the resource's value has already changed to the updated one. But its not reflecting in the view.

The problem here is because your `ThemeChanged` event is triggered in main view, so it's running in main view's thread, therefore the `ThemeManager_ThemeChanged` method you've used in *SecondaryPage.xaml.cs* will also running in main view's thread. This leads to the `Application.Current.Resources` in `ThemeManager_ThemeChanged` method still get the `ResourceDictionary` instance associated with main view. That's why the resource's value has already changed to the updated one and won't reflect in the view. To see this clearly, you can take advantage of [Threads Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-threads-window) while debugging.

To solve this issue, you can use `this.Dispatcher.RunAsync` method to run your code in right thread like the following:

```
private async void ThemeManager_ThemeChanged(Utils.ThemeManager theme)
{
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        ((SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundBrush"]).Color = theme.HighAccentColorBrush.Color;
    });
}
```

However, with this you will still get an error like: "***The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.***" This is because [SolidColorBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush) class also inherits from [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject). To solve this issue, I'd suggest changing `HighAccentColorBrush` type from [SolidColorBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush) to [Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Color) and then use it like:

```
private async void ThemeManager_ThemeChanged(Utils.ThemeManager theme)
{
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        ((SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundBrush"]).Color = theme.HighAccentColorBrush;
    });
}
```

Comment: So if i have 100 themeresources you mean to say that i should have 100 static properties in my App.xaml.cs. Isn't the themeresource concept itself is becoming void now? Secondly the meaning for Application.Resources literally means the app's resources right? so it should be common for all views? or each view is treated as different app. i see some design level flaw here. if it works in the way you have mentioned. Can you check with your team and revert? Also default mail app handles this case? Can you enlighten me how they have handled this?

Comment: The application.current.resources in each window 'might' also be independant. Can you check with someone from the team and answer this in binary??

Comment: I have changed the code to modify the resource in each view. if you set a breakpoint in ThemeChanged method in SecondaryPage.xaml.cs before changing the value you can see that the resource's value has already changed to the updated one. But its not reflecting in the view. PS: check my latest code. https://github.com/Kumara-Krishnan/ThemePOC

Comment: @MojoJojo I've updated my answer to explain this, please have a check. For default mail app, I'm not sure how it handles this case, but it only used one color in secondary view, so I'd suppose my solution should work. I'm not sure why you need to change100 themeresources, as you can see in default mail app, it only changes one color.

Answer (score 0):

Use the theming this way.

In you theme page on button click add this logic

```
    void OnClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;

        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "ThemeButtonClicked", btn.BackgroundColor);

        Application.Current.Properties["Theme"] = btn.BackgroundColor;
        Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();

        Navigation.PopAsync(true);

    }
```

In all other pages subscribe to the above notification as shown below.

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Theme, Color>(this, "ThemeButtonClicked", OnThemeChanged);
```

Add this below method to execute when subscriber notifies.

```
  private void OnThemeChanged(Theme source, Color cl)
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = cl;
        layout.BackgroundColor = cl;

    }
```

So that all the open instances on the stack will also get the theme updated. Hope this answers your question.